# remoteObject Fails After Recompiling Using CF8

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, cfc, remoteobject

I've been handed a Flex project that was originally built and compiled using Flex3 and CF7.  My setup is Flex3 with CF8.  Everything works fine when I initially pull the project over but as soon as I recompile, remote calls to the CFCs begin to fail.  I used Charles Web Proxy debugger and discovered that the failure appears to begin with the flex2gateway.  I double checked to make sure the flex2gateway is accessible and it's working fine on my CF8 install from both my project root and localhost.  I also double checked to make sure that my project settings directed the Flex Compiler to reference my CF8 wwwroot for the services-config.xml.  As far as I can tell, all of my settings are correct.  So, needless to say, I'm at a complete loss.  Has anyone else encountered this problem before?

Thanks,
--Anne

Comment: Any additional information in the error?  Is there a fault passed up to Charles or perhaps an error in the CF logs?

Comment: No, no errors are thrown which is even more perplexing.  The only thing I've been able to determine is that the Flex App is simply not getting to the gateway to perform the AMF call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After toying with this for considerably longer than I ever should have, I've decided to use JSON for remoting instead.  This is mainly because JSON makes it considerably easier to find out what's going on under the covers when debugging.  Thanks for your help everyone.

--Anne

Answer (score 0):

Actually no errors are getting thrown which is really weird.  However, after some further testing and experimentation, I did find something rather interesting.  I went ahead and created a new project where the bin-debug files were all output to the web root.  When attempting to call a CFC with that setup, it worked fine which is kind of strange.  As soon as I started to set it up in the same file structure as the project, it stopped connecting.  The file structure of the project is as follows:

- _flash

  - main
  - bin-debug
  - libs
  - src
- com

  - Test

    - Test.cfc
- index.cfm  (this is the same as the html wrapper that's usually generated in bin-debug.  We have it in the root so that we can pull either the release or debug versions depending on which server we're using at the time.)

Based on this, my thought is that for some reason it's not looking to the server root for com.Test.Test and is instead just looking within bin-debug.  Does that make sense?  What's maddening is the utter lack of errors.

--Anne